# IO.File.Move doesn't work for files (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I am making a Program where you add files to an ListBox, and when you click the Install-Button it should move the files that got added to the ListBox, to an other folder. But this doesn't work, and i don't know how to fix. Here is my current Code:

```
   Private Sub MoveFileBackgroundWorker(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles mfb.DoWork
      For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items 'For each Items in ListBox1.Items, move.
        IO.File.Move(i, mcpath_ & "\mods\")
      Next
   End Sub
```

Any help is really appreciated! PS: Sorry if my English isn't good, i am German :)

Comment: How do you add items to `listbox1` ? Try debugging your code

Comment: I've add them through an OpenFileDialog, like this: `If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then ListBox1.Items.Add(ofd.FileName.ToString) End If `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how i fixed it:

```
IO.File.Move(i, IO.Path.Combine(mcpath_.Trim, "mods", IO.Path.GetFileName(i)))
```

You need to add at mcpath_ .Trim!

Answer (score 1):

`Move` works in the following way:

```
IO.File.Move("C:\\myfile1.txt", "D:\\myfile2.txt")
```

It takes the source file as the first argument, and the target file as the second argument. In other words, the line above will move the file `C:\myfile1.txt` to a file named `D:\myfile2.txt`

So your line should be

```
IO.File.Move(i, IO.Path.Combine(mcpath_, "mods", IO.Path.GetFileName(i))
```

Which means: move file stored in `i` to the folder `mcpath & "\mods\"` with the same file name and extension

Comment: The Problem is, i don't want to rename the file. Because of the ListBox1.Items, i can't rename them. If you, for example, add mutliple Items, how should i rename them? Is there an other way without renaming?

Comment: you can use `IO.Path.GetFileName(i)` to get the same filename, as explained in the answer

Comment: Good, i will try. Thx :)

Comment: It gives me now an error: "Invalid path characters"

Comment: IO.Path.Combine gives me the "Invalid path characters" error. Someone? Please?

Comment: Try to use a debugger and tell us what is the value of the variables _i_ and _mcPath_ at the point in which you get the error message

Comment: I get the error at "mods". Without it is it fine. MCPath is the Path to the folder where the files gets moved. i are the ListBox Items.

Comment: Path.Combine takes its input parameters and creates a path string including the backslashes. Do not add them yourself.

Comment: I've didn't add themselfs. And it still doesn't work!

Comment: Please show what the variable `s` contains: `Dim s = IO.Path.Combine(mcpath_, "mods", IO.Path.GetFileName(i)`

Comment: Nevermind, i've fixed it! mcpath_ contains the invalid characters, i've changed it to mcpath_.Trim and it works perfectly now!